# Clicking through Positioned Fontawesome Icon with CSS

Tags: css, css-transitions, font-awesome

I want that the font awesome icon should only appear on the hover of the image and that too over the image: top right of the image, but I am unable to accomplish this. I have created a sample code snippet replicating the issue.

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('lazy-mymodal');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById('lazyimg-popup');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#lazyimg-popup {
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

#lazyimg-popup:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 30px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (image) */
.modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1100px;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image */
#caption {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    max-width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 10px 0;
    height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation */
.modal-content, #caption {
    -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
    from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)}
    to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
    from {transform:scale(0)}
    to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #bbb;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}


.lazyimg i {
    top: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="lazyimg"> 
        <img id="lazyimg-popup" src="http://moimir.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/1.jpg" alt="Trolltunga, Norway" width="700px" height="auto">
<i class="fa fa-expand" aria-hidden="true"></i>                              
</div>

<!-- The Modal -->
                        <div id="lazy-mymodal" class="modal">
                          <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
                          <span class="img-close">&times;</span>                              
                          <div id="caption"></div>
                        </div>
```

```
<i class="fa fa-expand" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

> the above neeeds to be on hover, but not on the click. Just like the
>   image is clickable and enlarges into modal boxes the fontawesome icon
>   on click should also enlarge the same image in the modal box.

Comment: Please read the comment properly.

Comment: icon appears on hover , just change the font color and check

Comment: @chris happy, it seems to work. can u write the full correct answer so that i can accept. This needs to be added: pointer-events: none; Right?

Comment: I checked it 100% works. Please write an answer so that i can accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `pointer-events: none` to the **close button** and it'll allow you to click and hover through the icon.

[More info](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/pointer-events/)

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('lazy-mymodal');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById('lazyimg-popup');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.lazyimg {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
}

#lazyimg-popup {
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.full {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.lazyimg:hover .full {
    display: block;
}




#lazyimg-popup:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 30px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (image) */
.modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1100px;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image */
#caption {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    max-width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 10px 0;
    height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation */
.modal-content, #caption {
    -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
    from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)}
    to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
    from {transform:scale(0)}
    to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #bbb;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
    <div class="lazyimg">
        <img id="lazyimg-popup" src="http://moimir.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/1.jpg" alt="Trolltunga, Norway" width="700px" height="auto">
        <i class="fa fa-expand full" aria-hidden="true" style="pointer-events: none;"></i>
    </div>

    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div id="lazy-mymodal" class="modal">
        <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
        <span class="img-close">&times;</span>
        <div id="caption"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I think that your question has room for improvement. Make the title more relevant to the question and make a simple list of what you want the icon to be. If you do, you'll earn my upvote :)

Comment: Please edit the question as you are more experienced than me. Thanks.

Comment: How about I show you how? Let's talk [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148660/chris-room)